# NginX PHP in a second level subdir

Tags: nginx, configuration, php-fpm

I got a Laravel installation in `/srv/http/v1`. The index.php is within `/srv/http/v1/public` as usual with laravel. It is nginx running with php-fpm.

It should be mapped to this second level subdir `app.example.com/api/v1`

It can be called by `app.excampe.com/api/v1` without any problem. But e.g. `app.example.com/api/v1/anything` returns me a 404 from nginx. The route exists inside laravel and if not, the 404 should be the laravel one.

My current nginx config for the location is

```
location /api/v1 {
    include /etc/nginx/php_fastcgi_location.conf;
    alias /srv/http/v1/public;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/v1/index.php?$query_string;
}
```

I guess there is something wrong with try_files, but i got no clue :-( So i would welcome helpful hints.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution myself:

```
location /api/v1 {
    include /etc/nginx/php_fastcgi_location.conf;
    alias /srv/http/v1/public;
    index index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @apiv1;
}

location @apiv1 {
    rewrite /api/v1/(.*)$ /api/v1/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Although i have found this by trial and error, i would be happy if someone could explain the reason for the problem and the solution.